# Error thrown when injecting <Platform> in a unit test of a Service in Ionic

Tags: unit-testing, ionic3

I just started developing my first application with Ionic 3 and I am now in the process of making some unit tests. Now I am facing a problem "compiling" the a unit test of a `Service` when `Platform` is one of its dependencies.

Here is the abstract of the `Service`:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(public platform: Platform) {}

  myMethod(): Observable<any> {
    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      return new Observable(android);
    else if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      return new Observable(iOS);
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the Unit Test I made following some tutorials from the Internet:

```
describe('XXX', () => {
  var service: MyService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [MyService, Platform]
    });
  });

  it('should xxx', inject([MyService], (service) => {
    var result = service.mymethod();
    expect(result).toBeDefined();
  }));
});
```

The configuration for my tests has been made following this [blog post](https://blog.ionicframework.com/basic-unit-testing-in-ionic/). I have some other `spec` files that run successfully, except for this one that throws the following error:

```
PS C:\Workspaces\JS-TS\taccess> npm run test

> taccess@0.0.1 test C:\Workspaces\JS-TS\taccess
> karma start ./test-config/karma.conf.js --single-run

(node:17164) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
‼ ｢wdm｣:
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
‼ ｢wdm｣:
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.
26 07 2018 07:20:43.963:INFO [karma]: Karma v2.0.5 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
26 07 2018 07:20:44.003:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
26 07 2018 07:20:44.806:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
26 07 2018 07:20:54.988:INFO [Chrome 68.0.3440 (Windows 10 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket u2KlYyff-qRa_fnHAAAA with id 6508927
Chrome 68.0.3440 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught Error: Cannot find module './components/app/app-root'",
    "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught Error: Cannot find module './components/app/app-root'"
  }
Chrome 68.0.3440 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught Error: Cannot find module './components/app/app-root'",
    "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught Error: Cannot find module './components/app/app-root'"
  }

Chrome 68.0.3440 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.008 secs / 0 secs)


Chrome 68.0.3440 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.142 secs / 0 secs)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! taccess@0.0.1 test: `karma start ./test-config/karma.conf.js --single-run`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the taccess@0.0.1 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-26T05_20_56_762Z-debug.log
```

Why do I need to inject `Platform` into the Service? Because I am using the Cordova pluging for [BLE](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ble/) and there are some differences between iOS and Android than I need to manage.

**Has anyone any clue about what is happening? What am I doing wrong?**

**Note 1**: I have checked removing the dependency with `Platform` and the test (with some modifications due the lack of `Platform`) works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I have discovered what the problem is: Visual Studio Code.

For some reason VSCode changed this import

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
```

to this other

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular/umd';
```

As soon as I removed the `/umd` everyhting worked like a charm.

Hope this helps others in the future.